# Книга про Ассемблер поверхностно (с упором на современные компьютеры)

Tags: ассемблер, книги

Я учу C/C++. Какую книгу посоветуете мне чтобы не глубоко но достаточно изучить Assembler?
Как сказал [@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg):

> Ознакомится на требуемом уровне можно
> за месяц-полтора. Сразу изучайте
> плоскую модель. Всяких досовских
> заморочек даже не касайтесь, это
> совершенно ни к чему.

И какая книга соответствует этим критериям и (не пинайте за безграмотность :)) что такое "Плоская модель"?
PS: Плюс желательно чтоб книга описывала постепенно как работает компьютер (от поверхностного до необходимого)

Comment: В архитектурах, где размер памяти больше адресного слова, адрес формируется хитро, напр. адрес = адрес сегмента + (смещение в коде команды и, возможно, смещение в индекс-регистре) для удобства вводятся понятия моделей в зависимости от того, как организуется работа с использованием этих сегментных регистров (что не запрещает вручную использовать их иначе). Это всё для x86 было для 16-бит процессоров: i8086/i8088 ... i80286. Начиная с i80386 можно было адресовать всю память с помощью 32-бит адреса, модель стала "плоской", не разбитой на куски-сегменты. Хотя эта "плоская" -- 32-бит tiny/small

Comment: вики почитай поверхносно и не слушай мики-олдскульщика =)

Comment: @alexlz, к вашему сведению с участием современного assembler'а пишут avp 12  и keygen's вирусы и другие современные приложения для WIN7 IMHO

Comment: Вот эта фраза мне очень понравилась:

     keygen's вирусы и другие современные приложения для WIN7

Comment: @alexlz это была опечатка (как оказалось не изменяющая смысл :))

Comment: >не слушай мики-олдскульщика

Это Вы про меня?

Comment: С 80-х годов были добавлены некоторые дополнительные специальные регистры (MMX, SSE и др.) и команды для управления ими. В наборе основных команд все осталось с тех пор неизменным. Учить и тем более глубоко вникать в эти расширения смысла не вижу. Достаточно слегка ознакомиться с основными принципами.

Самое большое изменение с тех пор - архитектура х64. Но это уже другая история.

Comment: Ну кроме x64 следует ещё ARM'ы вспомнить (на PowerPC виндов не было, альфы -- давно прошлое).

Comment: @alexlz, а 20-25 лет назад было еще больше архитектур. Я имею ввиду IBM-совместимые процессоры.

Comment: @mikillskegg А винды на них были? Или MS DOS? Нет? Не считаем.

Comment: Вечерний тролль... Вечерний тролль... (Поем на мотив известной песни)

Comment: @mikillskegg А что Вы думаете про книгу посоветованную @insor? по моему она как раз то что нужно.. А привязка к MASM сейчас не критична (в FASM по моему такое не скомпилируется?)?

Comment: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

Вот вам самый лучший учебник по x86 ассемблеру на одну страницу. Удачи.

Comment: @Rules, да, там привязка к MASM, FASM такое без изменений не скомпилирует: в fasm обязательны квадратные скобки вокруг адресов, отсутствует директива offset (и другие директивы), и подключаемые файлы отличаются по именам и назначению. При необходимости это довольно легко исправляется. А книга ИМХО годная.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обзор книги Ч.Петцольда ["Код. Тайный язык информатики"](http://view.samurajdata.se/psview.php?id=6707634d&page=1&all=1). В конце собирается компьютер.

Самое худшее - поверхностная книга. Хорошая книга читается даже если и долго то навсегда. 
Для начала хочу кратко объяснить кто такой Петцольд. Это очень умный дядька, чьим мозгом навечно овладели Мелкомягкие и поставили на нём своё клеймо. Тем не менее, он имеет офигеть какую степень по математике со всеми вытекающими. И пусть книгу "Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software" выпустили в типографии мелкомягких, но в ней нет холивара на вечную тему "Unix vs Windows" (но мы ведь знаем, что это не вечный холивар ;)). Кто хочет узнать больше тем ссылка на англ.вики.

Итак, что из себя представляет сама книга?
Я сказал бы, что это пересказ истории развития электрических счетных устройств в то, что сегодня у нас используется повсеместно.  Рассказ начинается с построения простейших электрических цепей и объяснения приципа их действия. Далее объясняются, что такое системы исчисления и как переводить цифры из десятичной в двоичную системы. Ну а потом начинается суть книги, построение реле, сборка из них цепей, которые по сути своей являются какими-никакими счетными устройствами. Тут я хотел бы сразу предупредить, что не стоить тратить время на вглядывание в электрические цепи и попытки в голове прикинуть как-что-где переключится. Для каждой схемы будет дано грамотное объяснение действиям происходящим в цепи. Тут главное ухватить саму суть.
Отдельно разбираются основы языка Ассемблер. Этот низкоуровневый язык в наше время уже не используется, но в годах 70х-80х с ним работали так же много как сейчас с Java или C++. Для примеров с Ассемблером взят чип Intel 8080 и Motorola 68000. В итоге мы плавно переходим к разбору графических интерфесов. А точнее к видеопамяти и к тому как она работает.

Собственно автор в начале говорит, что он ставит задачу собрать компьютер по завершении книги, и на самом деле ему это удаётся. Мы действительно можем собрать свой собственный компьютер, если захотим. А если и не захотим, то понимание принципов работы компьютера это очень хороший пласт для тех, кто собирается работать с ним больше, чем с простой печатной машинкой. Рекомендую к прочтению всем, кроме тех кто её уже читал. ;)

Comment: > Этот низкоуровневый язык в наше время уже не используется

Хм...

Книга, конечно, годная, жалею что у меня ее не было в классе этак 3, я как раз такими вещами начинал интересоваться. Но, к сожалению, она не поможет изучить ассемблер для современных компьютеров, разве что косвенно.

Comment: @xsi всё равно спасибо!+1

Comment: @insolor, в третьем классе?

Comment: @strol, да. Тогда настольной книгой у меня была ["микроЭВМ своими руками"](http://zx.pk.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=22885&d=1292064657). Немного позже появился ZX Spectrum 48k.

Answer (score 4):

- FASM - (http://flatassembler.net/ - компилятор)

Достаточно долго сам искал литературу но решил остановится на уроках с сайтов:

- http://fasmworld.ru/uchebnik/ - пишется все под DOS, но в сочетании с этим: http://fasm.su/Lessons/01 будет самое оно.

Answer (score 4):

**С. Зубков - Assembler для DOS, Windows и UNIX** - очень подробно объясняет различные неочевидные заковырки подкрепляя их примерами.

**Таненбаум Э.- Архитектура компьютера** - для общего, но объемлющего представления о компьютере вполне достаточно.

Но если совсем поверхностно, то можно **В. Ю. Пирогов "Assembler. Учебный курс"** почитать.

Честно говоря, для изучения ассемблера как языка, достаточно изучить синтаксис(он очень простой, но так же имеется ввиду как делать процедуры, макросы, и т.п.), знать систему команд, а изучить ее вполне по силам за пару вечеров, и еще вечер на закрепить на практике, и вызубрить основные досовские функции или просто тупо распечать таблицу из них и собсно все, вы знаете ассемблер. Далее когда что-то пишете и не представляете как это сделать, открываете соответствующий раздел книги и изучаете как взаимодействовать с той или иной аппаратурой, как правило у начинающих проблемы именно из-за этого.

Но перед ассемблером настоятельно советую вспомнить информатику, что такое регистр, прерывания, как проводятся логические операции и т.п.

Что касается процессоров, то изучив интел пентиум 1 или его 16ти разрядного 86го предшественника, и основные принципы вычислений и работы с памятью, то вам легко будет понять как работает любой процессор. С тех пор мало что изменилось, основа одна и та же.

Comment: @Raskilas

    и еще вечер на закрепить на практике, и вызубрить основные досовские функции или просто тупо распечать таблицу из них и собсно все, вы знаете ассемблер

Что и требовалось доказать. Голимая археология. Изучение окаменевших экскрементов древних ящеров.

Мужики, вы ведь не для работы ассемблер изучаете?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что под "современными компьютерами" в вопросе имелись в виду современные операционные системы, а значит таблица прерываний совсем не в тему.

Comment: @alexlz, коммент к ответу @Raskilas.

Comment: @alexlz что вы подразумеваете под "Голимая археология" и что тогда не голимая не археология? @insolor ассемблер это инструмент нейрохирургии в то время как с/с++ это обычный скальпель, а java/c# вообще долото с молотком. Абсолютно любой транзисторный компьютер имеет систему прерываний, асм для того, чтобы практически на прямую взаимодействовать с аппаратурой, если кому-то это не нужно или не интересно, то пускай пишет на С, там компилятор уже на столько умен, что только на простых проектах проигрывает в производительности в 2-3 раза, на сложных не существенно. На С писать и быстрее и проще.

Comment: @Raskillas, система прерываний - это не часть языка ассемблер, а интерфейс ОС, а именно DOS, потому и археология. Вопрос же был о современных ОС, в частности о Windows, так что тут полезнее было бы знать WinAPI.

Comment: @Raskilas Эмоционально и непонятно. Где же я в 21м веке транзисторные-то компутеры найду? "Голимая археология" в данном случае -- MS DOS. Старая дурная система.

Аппаратура. Напрямую и асм и Си (в крайнем случае с asm-вставками) взаимодействуют с аппаратурой одинаково. За редкими исключениями (недавно здесь одна библиотека для расчётов  обсуждалась, только не помню автора, @avp напомнит, если что) программы на ассемблере хуже, чем программы на Си (но зато дороже). Микроскоп бывает нужен, но заставь Вас работать с компьютером, глядя на экран через микроскоп...

Comment: @insolor вопрос был о современных компьютерах, во вторых до висты винда была по-сути надстройкой дос, т.е. в основном апи инкапсулировало все те же пресловутые прерывания. @alexlz не знаю чего вам не понятно, но я сомневаюсь в вашей компетенции, до сих пор, все процессоры массового производства построены на транзисторах. Я заверяю вас, сам видел, ассемблерный код программы на Си, как правило, раза в 3 длиннее. Как я говорил, программа на ассемблере может быть хуже только в том случае, если ее писали кривые руки в огромном проекте. У доса свои применения, и не столь он стар.

Comment: >до висты винда была по-сути надстройкой дос

Последней такой виндой была Windows 3. Даже 95 уже была самостоятельной системой. Эх, молодежь.

>У доса свои применения, и не столь он стар

Ну оооочень узкая область применения. А система действительно дурацкая. И идея прерываний - дурацкая. И прямой доступ к оборудованию - вообще маразм.

Comment: @mikillskegg да, вероятно вы все же правы на счет Windows 3, хотя стоит отметить, что со всеми недостатками его космическая скорость работы и дешевизна, а если брать современные досы, то еще и бесплатность, находят применения. Например в пятерочке, на кассовых аппаратах, раньше стоял дос поголовно, сейчас вроде им дистр бсд запилили, в библиотеках недавно во всех дос стоял, в макдаке вроде стоял, а кое-где возможно и стоит). Но в питере разводка мостов управляется юниксом). Там где не требуется широкий функционал, и малые вычислительные мощности, там дос в тему.

Comment: @mikilskrgg Win3.0 -- последние винды, где был реальный режим работы. 3.1 -- стандартный (286) и 386й, в 3.11 вроде уже и стандартного не было. Но 9x/Линолеум -- это та же ветка. Другая система -- это WinNT и далее.

@Raskilias Как я понимаю, использование dos обусловлено наличием программ на FoxPro for dos (или чем-то подобном). Асм там не в тему. Его преимущество на слабых процессорах трудно оспаривать в случаях программ в несколько десятков-сотен команд. Дальше уже идёт задница. И назовите хотя бы один комп на транзисторах (или хотя бы транзисторных сборках)

Comment: открываем ссылку на википедии по Intel Ivy Bridge http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge и транзисторы, транзисторы, одни лишь транзисторы. Или для вас понятие компьютер включает несколько иное?

Comment: Где же там транзисторы? Транзисторы -- это такие небольшие детальки с тремя выводами в металлическом или пластмассовом корпусе (или без него). Компутеры на транзисторах назывались компутерами второго поколения. В СССР были пущены на слом в 70х-80х годах прошлого века.

На них программирование на языке Ассемблера было весьма популярно.

Comment: @alexlz ваш пафос не понятен, процессоры действительно состоят из транзисторов. Они не имеют внешних выводов и корпуса, выращиваются прямо на монокристале кремния в специальных вытравленных карманах и соединяются между собой при помощи металлопроводников.

Answer (score 3):

А.Б. Крупник "Ассемблер. Самоучитель" для ознакомления в самый раз.

Comment: @insolor а это современная книга? (В смысле информация в ней)

Comment: @Rules, это достаточно современная книга, в том смысле, что все что там описано (кроме главы про DOS) работает и под Win7.

Answer (score 3):

[wasm.ru](http://wasm.ru) тоже очень хороший портал, посвященный низкоуровневому программированию.